# ASP.NET & SQL Server connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a global value inside asp net for getting SQL Server connection string.

Should I create a public read only string?

```
public static readonly string connectionString="myconnection string";
```

inside a class?

Or do I need to add a key value inside `Web.Config`?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlDatabase"
         connectionString="yourConnectionString"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And to use it inside get or post request

```
public string Get(int id)
{
     var connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDatabase "].ConnectionString;
     return "connectionString";
}
```

This string will be used from many client request at same time.

Comment: Define the connection string in the `web.config`. You *could* create a static class with a static readonly public string property that is initialized in the static constructor of the class and reads in that value from the connection string once from the `web.config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your connection string in web config as

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DbContext" 
       connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=mydbname;
       Integrated Security=True"; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

now read from the application using this code

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["DbContext"].ConnectionString;
```

thats how you can use it across applications and can change the connection string from web config after deployment of the application

Comment: how would you use it to a `SQLConnection conn` variable?

Comment: read connection string using the second code block above, use that to initialize SQLConnection and enter connection string in param, on the left set it to variable conn, which will hold the connection the the DB

Answer (score 1):

It goes in your web.config or [appsettings.json (for .net core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings). Read about [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to learn more about the new/cool/easy way to handle all this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In cs file you can use it as:-
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection.connection_string"].ToString());

Comment: <appSettings> <add key="connection.connection_string" value="Data Source=datasourcename;Initial Catalog=userdb;User ID=user;Password=****" /></appSettings>